# E/CameraManagerGlobal: Camera service is unavailable on Xiaomi Device

Tags: android, android-camerax, xiaomi

For the past two weeks, I have been trying to fix this problem

```
E/CameraManagerGlobal: Camera service is unavailable
```

I have 3 Android phones, POCO X3 NFC (Android 12), REDMI NOTE 10  pro(Android 13), And Samsung s10edge. The camera works on Samsung and Redmi but it wouldn't work on Poco x3. It even works on emulators

The same code works on new projects I created. But today, I have managed to figure out the issue, The issue is the long Package name of the App.

- deleting .gradle .idea didn't fix the issue.

On The very same project, When I shorten the package name, The camera worked on Xiaomi Poco x3 NFC. But I cannot update the app on Playstore with a different package name. Here are the dependencies of the camera.

```
def camerax_version = '1.2.2'
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}"
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-mlkit-vision:1.3.0-alpha06'

implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.1.0'
```

Any idea, what should be done?

Comment: "When I shorten the package name, The camera worked on Xiaomi Poco x3 NFC" that's really interesting. If you lengthen it, would it work? If not, you might be triggering a rare bug somewhere. Could you provide a full logcat file?